# Servlet error in a program that searches a record using mvc

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, javabeans

Good day everyone,

First of all, Im new to the world of java. I have this task to create a program that will search for records using MVC. I have a code to begin with but I'm having an error. I hope someone could help me fix this as soon as possible.

EmpBean.java

```
package form;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class EmpBean {

public List dataList(){
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
try{
 Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("C:\\SoftdevWorkspace\\mvc\\WebContent\\employee.sql");
       Statement st=con.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from employee");
       while(rs.next()){
           list.add(rs.getString("name"));
           list.add(rs.getString("department"));
           list.add(rs.getString("email"));

}
}
catch(Exception e){}
return list;

}
}
```

BeanInServlet.java

```
package form;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

public class BeanInServlet extends HttpServlet{
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws ServletException, IOException{
    form.EmpBean p = new form.EmpBean();
    List list=p.dataList();

    req.setAttribute("data", list);
    RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/beandata.jsp");
    rd.forward(req, res);
}
}
```

beandata.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java"   contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1 "
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<table border="1" width="303">
<tr>
<td width="119"><b>Name</b></td>
<td width="168"><b>Address</b></td>
<td width="119"><b>Contact no</b></td>
<td width="168"><b>Email</b></td>
</tr>
<% Iterator itr;%>
<% List data=(List)request.getAttribute("data");
for(itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
%>
<tr>
<td width="119"><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td width="168"><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td width="119"><%=itr.next()%></td>
<td width="168"><%=itr.next()%></td>
</tr>
<%}%>
</table>
</html>
```

And here is the error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /beandata.jsp at line 19

16: </tr>
17: <% Iterator itr;%>
18: <% List data=(List)request.getAttribute("data");
19: for(itr=data.iterator(); itr.hasNext(); ){
20: %>
21: <tr>
22: <td width="119"><%=itr.next()%></td>
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Im Using Eclipse Indigo, Tomcat 7, SqliteDev

Comment: We don't really do **urgent**. If it was urgent you should have started on the assignment earlier ;)

Comment: First, adding each column to the same `List` is a bit odd. Second, you appear to only be adding 3 of the columns to the `List`, but printing 4. Third, you're calling `hasNext()` only one time but calling `next()` 4 times in a row.

Comment: Sorry for misused word. My bad. Promise not to do it again.

Comment: any suggestion in fixing my code? i mean. what am i going to do? i really dont know what to do next.

Comment: Try using a model (the 'M' in MVC); either a POJO or a `HashMap` instead of adding all the columns to the `List`. Ensure you call `hasNext` for each `next`.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try the For-each loop construct to see if that takes away the error.
Your program looks ok so far to me...

As rightly pointed out by @Normalocity, what have you tried so far to get rid of the problem?